# Responsive menu animation malfunction

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I've made this responsive slide in menu. I only added the code for the responsive view.

It works like this. By default are `div.overlay` and `ul` hidden. With a click on the `.triggerRM` anchor, all elements become an extra class called `.openRM`, this animates (with CSS-transition):

- `.overlay` makes a black cover over the body
- `.triggerRM` left position is changed from `0%` to `100%` (with a bit of margin and background change)
- `ul` right position gets changed from `100%` (hidden) to `5em`.

All works like a charm on my computer (Win 7 + FF38). But when looking with my Android phone the `ul` transition doesn't work. When the button is clicked, the background pops up at his end position without the animation.

The rest of the animation does work.

Any ideas??

Here 's the code:

**HTML**

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" class="triggerRM">Open menu</a>
    <div class="overlayRM"></div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 200;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #2849ee;
}
nav .triggerRM {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-indent: -1000%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: blue url(http://gvss.ragas1.nl/img/menu-rm-btn.png) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 50%;
    -moz-background-size: 50% 50%;
    -o-background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
}
nav ul,
nav .triggerRM,
nav .overlayRM {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
nav ul.openRM {
    left: 0;
    right: 5em;
}
nav .overlayRM.openRM {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 190;
}
nav .triggerRM.openRM {
    left: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://gvss.ragas1.nl/img/menu-rm-btn-close.png);
    margin-left: -5em;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    // Responsive menu 
    $("nav .triggerRM, nav .overlayRM").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("nav .triggerRM,nav ul,body,.overlayRM").toggleClass('openRM');
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3e2cbda/2/)
[**JSFiddle full page result**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3e2cbda/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: what browser do you use on Android phone?

Comment: Default browser from HTC one X (Android 4.2.2)